# Virtualbox guest additions build fails on kernel upgrade from 5.11.0-46-generic to 5.13.0-30-generic on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: kernel, virtualbox, update-manager, shared-folders

I'm running Linux vbubuntu 5.11.0-46-generic #51~20.04.1-Ubuntu in a virtualbox v6.1.18 hosted on Win10

After the Ubuntu software update the shared mounts with the host are no longer accessible and files on the share are no longer visible in Linux. They still do exist on the host. Noticed permission changed from

```
:/mnt$ ll
total 8,0K
4,0K drwxr-xr-x  6 root root   4,0K mrt  2  2021 ./
4,0K drwxr-xr-x 20 root root   4,0K mrt  2  2021 ../
   0 drwxrwx---  1 root vboxsf    0 feb 16 14:38 gdrive/
```

to

```
:/mnt$ ll
total 8,0K
4,0K drwxr-xr-x  6 root root   4,0K mrt  2  2021 ./
4,0K drwxr-xr-x 20 root root   4,0K mrt  2  2021 ../
   0 drwxr-x---  1 root root    0 feb 16 14:38 gdrive/
```

Manually altered the permissions and ownership back as they were before the update, but still no files are shown in the directory mounted for the shared folder. Upon further investigation the issue is caused by the update for the kernel from 5.11.0-46-generic to 5.13.0-30-generic.

The error message shown in vboxadd-setup.log is

```
Building the main Guest Additions 6.1.18 module for kernel 5.13.0-30-generic.
Building the shared folder support module.
Error building the module.  Build output follows.
make V=1 CONFIG_MODULE_SIG= CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_ALL= -C /lib/modules/5.13.0-30-generic/build M=/tmp/vbox.0 SRCROOT=/tmp/vbox.0 -j4 modules
make[1]: warning: -j4 forced in submake: resetting jobserver mode.
test -e include/generated/autoconf.h -a -e include/config/auto.conf || (                \
echo >&2;                                                       \
echo >&2 "  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.";           \
echo >&2 "         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.";\
echo >&2 "         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.";      \
echo >&2 ;                                                      \
/bin/false)
make -f ./scripts/Makefile.build obj=/tmp/vbox.0 \
single-build= \
need-builtin=1 need-modorder=1
```

The configuration file does exist in `/lib/modules/5.13.0-30-generic/build/include/generated/autoconf.h` and I for what I know I do not notice an error in the file. Both the old autoconf.h and the new autoconf.h file do define the virtualbox filesystem

```
#define CONFIG_VBOXSF_FS_MODULE 1
```

I do not run/create the OS nor kernel from sourcecode so the solution suggested in the error message is no option for me.

I do hope someone is able to help me

Comment: What you have here are kernel versions not the version of the OS. What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Answer (score 0):

Updated virtualbox to the latest version 6.1.32 on the host, and updated the extension pack.
Than started the ubuntu VM and updated the guest additions successfully before I updated the linux kernel.

content of the latest vboxadd-setup.log

```
Building the main Guest Additions 6.1.32 module for kernel 5.13.0-30-generic.
Building the shared folder support module.
Building the graphics driver module.
```

This solved the issue for me